# Id of an item in QTreeWidget changed

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget

There is something very strange about Qt.

I have a button `ui->addPointButton` and a QtreeWidget `ui->pointListBox`. When I click on the button, it adds a point to the tree. `mScenePtr` is a pointer to the class I put all my points.`AddPoint` is a class creating a window asking for some information about the point.

```
void AddPointsWindow::on_addPointButton_clicked(bool clicked)
{
    Q_UNUSED(clicked);

    AddPoint addPointWindow(mScenePtr->getColor_or_texture());
    int addPointWindowResult = addPointWindow.exec();

    if  (addPointWindowResult == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        SVertex vertex = addPointWindow.getVertex();
        mScenePtr->addVertex(vertex);

        QTreeWidgetItem* itemPtr = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->pointListBox);
        cout << "id" << ui->pointListBox->indexOfTopLevelItem(itemPtr) << endl;

        //itemPtr->setText(0,QString::number(mScenePtr->getVertexNumber()));
        //itemPtr->setText(0, QString::number(ui->pointListBox->indexOfTopLevelItem(itemPtr)));
        itemPtr->setText(0, "hjhjh");
        cout << "id" << ui->pointListBox->indexOfTopLevelItem(itemPtr) << endl;

        itemPtr->setText(1, QString::number(vertex.x));
        itemPtr->setText(2, QString::number(vertex.y));
        itemPtr->setText(3, QString::number(vertex.z));
        if (color == mScenePtr->getColor_or_texture())
        {
            itemPtr->setText(4, QString::number(vertex.r));
            itemPtr->setText(5, QString::number(vertex.g));
            itemPtr->setText(6, QString::number(vertex.b));
        }
        //ui->pointListBox->insertTopLevelItem(ui->pointListBox->topLevelItemCount(), itemPtr);



        cout << "value : " << vertex.x << endl;

    }
}
```

In this exemple, I click twice on the buttons, create two points with `vertex.x` = 0 for the first and 1 for the second.

Look at the three lines in the middle :

```
            //itemPtr->setText(0,QString::number(mScenePtr->getVertexNumber()));
        //itemPtr->setText(0, QString::number(ui->pointListBox->indexOfTopLevelItem(itemPtr)));
        itemPtr->setText(0, "hjhjh");
```

If there is only the third line, the result is

```
id0
id0
value : 0
id1
id1
value : 1
```

Everythong is ok.
But if I put one of the two others lines, the result in both cases is :

```
id0
id0
value : 0
id1
id0
value : 1
```

How is it possible ? How can the call to `ui->pointListBox->indexOfTopLevelItem(itemPtr)` or `mScenePtr->getVertexNumber()` can change the id of the item ?

Qt 5.5

Answer (score 0):

After using `setText`, the items in the tree might have sorted automatically.

So in the two commented line cases, when you add the number (using `setText`), the nodes are getting sorted and the earlier node has become the top level item.

That is the reason you are seeing two different IDs "before `setText`" and "after `setText`", when you are querying "top level item".

To see the results properly, Turn off the sorting for the tree. (may be in your constructor)

```
ui->pointListBox->setSortingEnabled(false);
```